# Unable to import locally published Scala plugin

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I have a project which I publish locally to my `.m2` directory as a plugin, which later I need to import into a different Scala project and use it.
It seems like the publishing step is executed correctly.
The `build.sbt` file of the plugin project looks like this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(SbtPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "pluginName",
    organization := "com.myOrg",
    pluginCrossBuild / sbtVersion := {
      scalaBinaryVersion.value match {
        case "2.12" => "1.4.6" // set minimum sbt version
      }
    }
  )

resolvers += "confluent" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "io.confluent"    % "kafka-schema-registry-client" % "7.0.1"
      // some other dependemcies
    )
```

After running the `compile` and `publishLocal` commands in sbt shell I get the next message:

```
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/me/Work/repos/external/pluginName/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/ivy-1.0.0.xml
[info]  published pluginName to /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.myOrg/pluginName/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.0/poms/pluginName.pom
[info]  published pluginName to /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.myOrg/pluginName/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.0/jars/pluginName.jar
[info]  published pluginName to /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.myOrg/pluginName/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.0/srcs/pluginName-sources.jar
[info]  published pluginName to /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.myOrg/pluginName/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.0/docs/pluginName-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.myOrg/pluginName/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 3 Jan 2022, 10:07:43
```

In order to import/install this plugin in the other Scala project, I have added the next line to the `plugins.sbt` file: `addSbtPlugin("com.myOrg" % "pluginName" % "1.0.0")`
I also added `libs-release-local` and `libs-snapshot-local` to the `externalResolvers` section in the `buid.sbt` file.

After reloading and compiling the project I received this error:

```
    [error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:7.0.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/confluent/kafka-schema-registry-client/7.0.1/kafka-schema-registry-client-7.0.1.pom
[error]   not found: /Users/me/.ivy2/local/io.confluent/kafka-schema-registry-client/7.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/io.confluent/kafka-schema-registry-client/7.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/io.confluent/kafka-schema-registry-client/7.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
```

I am kind of new to Scala and I don't understand what and I doing wrong.
Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're publishing to your local Maven cache, but sbt uses Ivy.

Try removing the `publishTo` setting, it shouldn't be needed. Just use the `publishLocal` task to publish to your local Ivy cache.

Comment: So I did some changes, as you suggested. Now it seems like it is able to find the published project, but it has a problem loading one of its dependencies. I have updated the question to reflect the current status.

Comment: You'll need the Confluent repo resolver as well in client projects using the plugin.